# Total of replacements in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to use `QString::replace` with `QRegularExpression` and count how many times it has replaced strings?

For example, imagine that I have a string: `xaxbxc`, and I want to replace `x` with `-`, is there any way to know how many times `QRegularExpression` replaced? In this case it would return "3".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `QRegularExpression::match()` instead? That would return a `QRegularExpressionMatch` object, and you could use the `QRegularExpressionMatch::capturedTexts()` to get a QStringList of the texts. From there, you can get the count from the `QStringList::count()` method.

Comment: The way you said is he same as doing `QString::count(QRegularExpression)`, but I have to replace and get the total at the same time, not only count the matches.

Comment: @volebab - just write a simple function that counts the replacements

Comment: @ddriver - I think that I will do that, a function that counts first, replaces after and return the count.